# Using WebEX API with PHP

Tags: php, webex

I am a beginner to using Webex API. I went through the documentation and couple of links([How can I use the WebEx URL/XML API to register a user for an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682359/how-can-i-use-the-webex-url-xml-api-to-register-a-user-for-an-event)) for an understanding of how it works. But while trying to use it, I get some errors and I am not receiving the intended result. If someone could give me a brief introduction on how it works, it would be great.

I want to access the login page in the webex API. By documentation, it goes of the name (p.php?AT=LI) and I tried to access the same using WebEX ID and Password which are the mandatory fields(as given in the documentation), I did not include the back URL. While giving this thing, I am receiving this error **AT=LI&ST=FAIL&RS=UnknownATCommand**.

Also I have these details. I have WebEX username, password, site ID and Partner ID. By WebEX ID, what does it mean ? Does WebEX ID and Partner ID one and the same?

Any help on this topic is highly appreciable.

Thanks & Regads,
Ramkumar

Comment: I fixed this issue. But I am facing another issue "BadWebExIDOrPassword". I know it is due to wrong web ID. I have WebEX username,Partner ID and Site ID. But I do not have Web ID. Could someone please let me know whether it is a different parameter ?

Comment: it would be very useful if you put a short description of how you fixed your problem...that's the whole point of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Webex Xml API,
Your XML headers must have these elements

`<header>
        <securityContext>
            <siteID>xxxx</siteID>
            <webExID>siteadmin</webExID>
            <password>password</password>
        </securityContext>
    </header>`

I think you use URL API, its different